# `httpsCallable` vs. `httpsCallableFromURL` callable Firebase Functions

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

`httpsCallableFromURL` is working correctly but `httpsCallable` is returning `null`. What's wrong?

The emulator logs show that the Cloud Function executes correctly from both `httpsCallableFromURL` and `httpsCallable`. My browser console logs `UPPERCASE` (if I enter `uppercase`) with `httpsCallableFromURL`. But with `httpsCallable` the browser console logs `null`.

It seems like `null` logs almost instantly but `UPPERCASE` takes a moment to log. My guess is that the return is executing before the function?

And another question. I found the URL in the Firebase Console in the list of Functions, for the deployed function. Is there somewhere in the emulator where I can find the URL for calling the function in the emulator? This URL was written by Github Copilot! This URL also works: `http://localhost:5001/my-projectId/us-central1/upperCaseMe`

*index.ts*

```js
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";

export const upperCaseMe = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    const original = data.text;
    const uppercase = original.toUpperCase();
    functions.logger.log('upperCaseMe', original, uppercase);
    return uppercase;
});
```

*app.component.ts*

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { getFunctions, httpsCallable, httpsCallableFromURL } from "firebase/functions";
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {
  firebaseConfig = environment.firebaseConfig;
  firebaseApp = initializeApp(this.firebaseConfig);

  messageText: any;
  functions = getFunctions(this.firebaseApp);

  callMe(messageText: any) {
    console.log("Calling Cloud Function: " + messageText);
    // const upperCaseMe = httpsCallable(this.functions, 'upperCaseMe');
    const upperCaseMe = httpsCallableFromURL(this.functions, 'http://127.0.0.1:5001/my-projectId/us-central1/upperCaseMe');
    upperCaseMe({ text: messageText })
      .then((result) => {
        console.log(result.data)
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });;
  };
}
```

I was able to make `httpsCallableFromURL` return `null`:

```
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";

export const upperCaseMe = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    const original = data.text;
    const uppercase = original.toUpperCase();
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log("Wait ten seconds.");
        functions.logger.log('upperCaseMe', original, uppercase);
        return uppercase;
      }, 10000)
});
```

This never logs anything in the emulator and always logs `null` in the browser console. It logs `null` after a second or two, not ten seconds. Same results with `httpsCallableFromURL` and `httpsCallable`.

Comment: You should discard the final code sample entirely and remove it from the question because it will never send what you expect back to the client.  The `return` is returning from the setTimeout lambda function, not the onCall function.  The onCall function is always going to return undefined no matter how you invoke it.

Answer (score 1):

`httpsCallable` uses your deployed code hosted by Cloud Functions by default.  The URL is derived from the data you passed during initialization of the Firebase SDK.  It does not use the emulator unless you configure the SDK to do so.  I suggest reviewing the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator#instrument-functions) on the matter.

> To instrument your app to interact with the emulators, you may need to
> do some additional configuration.
>
> If your prototype and test activities involve callable backend
> functions, configure interaction with the Cloud Functions for Firebase
> emulator like this:
>
> ```
> import { getApp } from "firebase/app";
> import { getFunctions, connectFunctionsEmulator } from "firebase/functions";
>
> const functions = getFunctions(getApp());
> connectFunctionsEmulator(functions, "localhost", 5001);
> ```

`httpsCallableFromURL` is for cases when you cannot use the normal way that the SDK locates the backend, for example, if you are hosting the callable function on some service that is not a normal Cloud Functions backend, or you are trying to invoke a function in a project that's not part of your app.

I would never expect Copilot to generate the correct code under any circumstance.  It's better to lean on the documentation to tell you what to do.

Answer (score 0):

I initialized Firebase incorrectly. Firebase should be initialized in `app.module.ts`, not in `app.component.ts`. Firebase should then be injected into `app.component.ts`. When I initialized Firebase correctly then both `httpsCallable` and `httpsCallableFromURL` returned the UPPERCASE message to the browser console.

*app.module.ts*

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

// Angular
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

// AngularFire
import { provideFirebaseApp, initializeApp } from '@angular/fire/app';
import { provideFunctions,getFunctions, connectFunctionsEmulator } from '@angular/fire/functions';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    provideFirebaseApp(() => initializeApp(environment.firebase)),
    provideFunctions(() => {
      const functions = getFunctions();
      if (!environment.production) {
        connectFunctionsEmulator(functions, 'localhost', 5001);
      }
      return functions;
    }),
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I changed the view to pass the message only via `ngModel`. Passing the message via `callMe(messageText)` was redundant.

*app.component.html*

```
<h3>Call cloud function</h3>
<form (ngSubmit)="callMe()">
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="messageText" name="message" placeholder="message" required>
    <button type="submit" value="Submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

I changed the component controller to inject `Functions` rather than initialize Firebase in the component controller:

*app.component.ts*

```js
import { Component, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { Functions, httpsCallable, httpsCallableFromURL } from '@angular/fire/functions';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {
  constructor(
    @Inject(Functions) private readonly functions: Functions,
  ) {}

  messageText: string = '';

  callMe() {
    console.log("Calling Cloud Function: " + this.messageText);
    const upperCaseMe = httpsCallable(this.functions, 'upperCaseMe');
    // const upperCaseMe = httpsCallableFromURL(this.functions, 'http://127.0.0.1:5001/languagetwo-cd94d/us-central1/upperCaseMe');
    upperCaseMe({ text: this.messageText })
      .then((result) => {
        console.log(result.data)
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });;
  };
}
```

No changes to `index.ts`.

As for Doug Stevenson's comment that the last code block in my question made him cringe, I reread the Cloud Functions documentation [Sync, async, and promises](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions) which explained that `return` is synchronous and promises are async. I promise never to put a `return` in a promise again!